# What determines the table load time from ODBC?

Tags: sql, r, odbc, stata

I have been recently using R's RODBC package to query from a ODBC. One limitation I encounter is the time it takes to load a table compared to, for example, Stata's odbc function. Loading the same table takes less time when loading it from Stata compared to R, which is quite frustrating. I certainly know nothing about ODBC architecture so I don't know if this is a newbie question but it's intriguing me.

Comment: I guess you need reproducible examples to make this concrete. Times can depend very sensitively on so many details of machine, network, internet connection?, size and kind of dataset, etc.

Comment: If your DB supports it, you can try using JDBC or something uses the API, like bigrquery package for BigQuery. I have often found those to be a bit faster.